# MSSQL at Docker exits instantly

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to setup MSSQL at Docker at Windows 10, but for some reason it started shutting down my container

I've been using it like that for months, but now I have no idea what's happening

```
    C:\Users\user\
    λ docker ps -a
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES

    C:\Users\user\
    λ docker login
    Authenticating with existing credentials...
    Login Succeeded

    C:\Users\user\
    λ docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=<YourStrong!Passw0rd>123' -p 1433:1433 --name sql -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
    337e5efb35f0bf4b465181a0f8be4851b12f353a3a8710ddf817d2f501e5fea

    C:\Users\user\
    λ docker ps -a
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
    347q5effb3cf0        mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest   "/opt/mssql/bin/sqls…"   3 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds        0.0.0.0:1433->1433/tcp   sql

    C:\Users\user\
    λ docker ps -a
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
    347q5effb3cf0        mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest   "/opt/mssql/bin/sqls…"   6 seconds ago       Exited (1) 2 seconds ago                       sql

    C:\Users\user\
    λ docker start sql
    sql

    C:\Users\user\
    λ docker ps -a
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
    347q5effb3cf0        mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest   "/opt/mssql/bin/sqls…"   14 seconds ago      Up 2 seconds        0.0.0.0:1433->1433/tcp   sql

    C:\Users\user\
    λ docker ps -a
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS               NAMES
    347q5effb3cf0        mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest   "/opt/mssql/bin/sqls…"   16 seconds ago      Exited (1) 1 second ago                       sql
```

> docker logs sql

shows

> The SQL Server End-User License Agreement (EULA) must be accepted before SQL
>   Server can start. The license terms for this product can be downloaded from
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=746388.
>
> You can accept the EULA by specifying the --accept-eula command line option,
>   setting the ACCEPT_EULA environment variable, or using the mssql-conf tool.
>   The SQL Server End-User License Agreement (EULA) must be accepted before SQL
>   Server can start. The license terms for this product can be downloaded from
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=746388.
>
> You can accept the EULA by specifying the --accept-eula command line option,
>   setting the ACCEPT_EULA environment variable, or using the mssql-conf tool.

Anybody has an idea what may be wrong?

Comment: Try removing the quotes around ACCEPT_EULA & SA_PASSWORD:
`docker run -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y -e exec SA_PASSWORD=<YourStrong!Passw0rd>123 --name sql -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest`

Comment: @GarethLyons ``The specified file can not be found.``

Comment: sorry, there's an unintentional exec in the middle there. Should be `docker run -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y -e SA_PASSWORD=<YourStrong!Passw0rd>123 --name sql -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest`

Comment: @GarethLyons Nope :/ ``C:\Users\user>docker run -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y -e SA_PASSWORD=<YourStrong!Passw0rd>123 --name sql -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
The specified file can not be found.``

Comment: What's the environment? Host Windows with Linux image?

Comment: @GarethLyons Windows 10 + Docker Desktop with Linux-ish Containers

Comment: Ok, just switched mine to Linux; get the same error using single quotes but it works with double quotes `docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=<YourStrong!Passw0rd>123" -p 1433:1433 --name sql -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest`

Comment: @GarethLyons Well, thanks :) Please write it as an answer, so i'll be able to accept

Answer (score 40, accepted):

When running Linux containers from Windows command line/Powershell, the environmental options (-e) require double quotes

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=<YourStrong!Passw0rd>123" -p 1433:1433 --name sql -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
```

Comment: Additionally, it will not accept simple passwords! 'g1234' like passwords will not be accepted and the container will not run. Password must be strong, like 'G@1234asdf' in order to be accepted and keep do container running.